Recaptcha not displaying after March 28th update (from Nate Dudley Original Poster)
Recaptcha had an update on March 28, 2024 and after the update console errors started appearing with this message: recaptcha__en.js:600 Uncaught TypeError: Ay is not a function
Recently we identified the same error on the lib, is there any workaround or update to this error?
recaptcha__en.js:600 Uncaught TypeError: Ay is not a function
    at recaptcha__en.js:600:139
    at Array.<anonymous> (recaptcha__en.js:164:51)
    at recaptcha__en.js:598:365
    at recaptcha__en.js:1035:83

thanks so much for any advice

I don't know if this is right answer but it maybe something todo with having a 'Cloud Billing Account' associated to the project in Google Cloud.
